# How to create an auto complete address field in SugarCRM using Google's Places Autocomplete api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, sugarcrm

I want to create an address field in which when we start entering an address we get hints using the Google's Places autocomplete api. Any ideas on how we can achieve this in Sugar? I searched for the solution online but couldn't find any relevant to SugarCRM. I am using the latest version of Sugar i.e. 7.6.1 Enterprise.

Would appreciate your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such thing at the moment. I would suggest writing a package that adds this functionality using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/?hl=de.
Should be pretty simple and usage wouldn't cost a dime till 2500 requests per day

Comment: appreciate your help! and sorry for such a late reply I was away for past week, I am actually new to SugarCRM and do not exactly know how to add customised javascript code in Sugar v7. I have played with logic hooks before but they were all in php. I am not asking for a complete solution but a little bit of more guidance or ideas which could help on how exactly I could add javascript code and how to fiddle with DOM elements or fields in SugarCRM interface.